# Launch titanium picker view when a button is pressed

Tags: android, android-layout, titanium, titanium-mobile

As I came to know that we cannot use custom image or background/border/text color in pickerview in titanium yet.

So I came up with the idea of showing a button to the user with custom image/font, and when user clicks the button, the picker view rows are shown just as if launched by clicking the picker view. Is it possible?

So **My Question**: How can launch a picker view when a button is clicked.

Comment: Did not get you exactly..

Comment: @KrishnaKumar I have edited my question. Please have a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also try Titanium.UI.OptionDialog, you can change this and in stead of having the event listener in the window you can have it in another custom view which can be used as a button.

```
Ti.UI.setBackgroundColor('white');
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
  title: 'Click window to test',
  backgroundColor: 'white',
  exitOnClose: true,
  fullscreen: false
});

var opts = {
  cancel: 2,
  options: ['Confirm', 'Help', 'Cancel'],
  selectedIndex: 2,
  destructive: 0,
  title: 'Delete File?'
};

win.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  var dialog = Ti.UI.createOptionDialog(opts).show();
});
win.open();
```

Comment: Yeaahhhhhh,,, thats "exacatly" what I wanted. Where were you earlier?

Answer (score 2):

Use This:

```
btn.addEventListener('click', function(){

  //Do your picker initialization (Picker code is taken from titanium docs)

  var picker = Ti.UI.createPicker({
  top:50,
  useSpinner: true
});
picker.selectionIndicator = true;

var fruit = [ 'Bananas', 'Strawberries', 'Mangos', 'Grapes' ];
var color = [ 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'orange' ];

var column1 = Ti.UI.createPickerColumn();

for(var i=0, ilen=fruit.length; i<ilen; i++){
  var row = Ti.UI.createPickerRow({
    title: fruit[i]
  });
  column1.addRow(row);
}

var column2 = Ti.UI.createPickerColumn();

for(var i=0, ilen=color.length; i<ilen; i++){
  var row = Ti.UI.createPickerRow({ title: color[i] });
  column2.addRow(row);
}

picker.add([column1,column2]);

win.add(picker);

});
```